# Why RecyclerView.ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition() returns -1?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, notifydatasetchanged

I've implemented a RecyclerView successfully and recently encountered a fringe use case upon removing some items from the view.

I pass in the view holder to a method `RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder` and then access the ViewHolder method `getAdapterPosition()` like so:

`int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();`

The problem is that after calling this a few times. (After removing a few items.) It sets the position as `-1`. I know this due to the logs. I also know that when the first item is removed there is no problem and the `notifyDataSetChanged()` is being called.

Is these another specific update method that can ensure the position is never returned as -1 besides an inline check?

**UPDATE:** `getAdapterPosition()` was returning `NO_POSITION` because the layout pass hadn't occurred since the last `notifyDataSetChanged()` call. Using `getLayoutPosition()` solves the -1 return issue.

Comment: can you post the entire  code snippet? as to know why exactly are you passing the entire ViewHolder object?  May be, there will be some other work around

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()

Comment: Ah thanks @pskink, I see now that for some reason the layout pass wasn't updating after `notifyDataSetChanged()` so I was getting `NO_POSITON` returned. Interesting... So I've changed it to `int position = viewHolder.getLayoutPosition();` and it seems to be working correctly now.

Comment: @Kishita, I'm using the entire ViewHolder because I'm using: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html#onSwiped(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20int) 

It's a bit lengthy to post the entire connected code, which is why I stuck to my specific question about the cause of  `viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()` returning -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The viewholder item is removed.

**#getAdapterPosition() return:**
The adapter position of the item if it still exists in the adapter. NO_POSITION if item has been removed from the adapter,

where NO_POSITION = -1

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()

Comment: Well I did update my question with an answer a few minutes before this post, but I'll accept it because it is what I asked and I didn't post a self answer first.